# Can someone explain to me which sentence is grammatically correct...?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

> I would like to inform you that I haven’t yet received the acknowledgement receipts of two files that I **had submitted**.

or

> I would like to inform you that I haven’t yet received the acknowledgement receipts of two files that I **submitted**.

Which tense should I use?

Answer (score -1):

The **past perfect** ("had submitted") refers to time previous to a *past event*.  Your first sentence sounds odd to me because that past event (the arrival of receipts) never occurred.  It would make sense to say

> I *expected* two transmission receipts yesterday for the files I **had
>   submitted**.

The past event was your expectation yesterday.  The past perfect means that you submitted the files before then.

Your second sentence is fine.  The *simple past* ("submitted") marks a *past event*, and the **present perfect** ("haven't received") covers the time from submission up to the present.

Comment: I'm going to add a suggestion that I didn't place in the answer, but it would be better if you simplified your English.  You start out with six unnecessary words "I would like to inform you" that your correspondent has no interest in, and you bury the point of interest (two files) at the end.  Better to say, "I submitted two files yesterday, but I haven't received the transmission receipts for them."  Not only is this shorter and clearer, but you don't have to agonize over verb tenses.